# Confused in a very complex sentence

Tags: grammar

I am not sure whether the last part of this sentence is grammatically right:

> My dream is to see an innovation of mine is one day being used inside automotive industry, such as General Motors or NASA, **so that I would have [played an important role / made and important contribution] in the high-end technologies.**

What I mean by the above sentence is that: "I want to invent something that will be used by those famous companies, and if that happens, then I have made an important contribution."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My dream is to see one day, that an innovation of mine is being used inside automotive industry, such as General Motors or NASA, so that I would have played a made and important contribution in the high-end technologies.

- That first comma doesn't need to be there.
- I have a hard time thinking of NASA as *automotive industry* — they used to do space exploration and stuff. Have they diversified?
- A “made and important” contribution makes little sense. Yes, you can use *made* as an adjective, but in this context the meaning is unclear.
- You *make* a contribution or you *play* a role. Playing a contribution can maybe happen at a concert, but you do not seem to be talking about music.
- “The high-end technologies” make me wonder how many there are. Simply using “high-end technology” is fine.

So, maybe something like this comes closer to what you mean:

> My dream is to see one day that an innovation of mine is being used by a major company, such as General Motors or NASA, so that I would have made and important contribution to  high-end technology.

Comment: @Murat: actually, I forgot to implement my own last point. _In_ and _to_ can both be used, by the way. In this case I do prefer _to_, so I have changed it accordingly. You can make a contribution _in_ a field, e.g. make a contribution in the field of medical science. In this case, the sentence is long enough without such fillers :)

Comment: Actually, NASA isn’t a company at all; it’s a part of the U.S. Government. It would be better to say, “… used by a major organization, such as General Motors or NASA, …” or perhaps “… a major entity, …”. (But “General Motors” and “NASA” is a peculiar pairing.) Also, I believe “made and important contribution” is a typo for “made ***an*** important contribution”.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "My dream is to see that one day..." Rather than "My dream is to see one day that..." ?